# Existing 3-function callback to Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a general question with a specific example:  I'd like to use Kotlin coroutine magic instead of callback hell in Android when taking a picture.

```
manager.openCamera(cameraId, object : CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
    override fun onOpened(openedCameraDevice: CameraDevice) {
        println("Camera onOpened")
        // even more callbacks with openedCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest()....
    }

    override fun onDisconnected(cameraDevice: CameraDevice) {
        println("Camera onDisconnected")
        cameraDevice.close()
    }
    ...
```

How would I convert that to something less ugly?  ***Is it possible to take an average callback with three or so functions, and turn it into a promise-chain by designating the primary flow as the promise-result path?*** And if so, should/do I use coroutines to make it async?

I'd love something with async and .await that would result in

```
manager.open(cameraId).await().createCaptureRequest()
```

I'm trying to do it through something like the following, but I don't think I'm using `CompletableDeferred` right!

```
suspend fun CameraManager.open(cameraId:String): CameraDevice {
    val response = CompletableDeferred<CameraDevice>()
    this.openCamera(cameraId, object : CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        override fun onOpened(cameraDevice: CameraDevice) {
            println("camera onOpened $cameraDevice")
            response.complete(cameraDevice)
        }

        override fun onDisconnected(cameraDevice: CameraDevice) {
            response.completeExceptionally(Exception("Camera onDisconnected $cameraDevice"))
            cameraDevice.close()
        }

        override fun onError(cameraDevice: CameraDevice, error: Int) {
            response.completeExceptionally(Exception("Camera onError $cameraDevice $error"))
            cameraDevice.close()
        }
    }, Handler())
    return response.await()
}
```

Comment: Chaining callbacks works if there ale multiple callbacks *in sequence*, each providing a result or error. <s>Here are two callbacks *in parallel*, how do you imagine chaining two callbacks at once? Which one does your sample pick?</s> Oh, primary flow. But you still need to close it onDisconnected, how do you chain it?

Answer (score 280, accepted):

In this particular case you can use a general approach to convert a callback-based API to a suspending function via `suspendCoroutine` function:

```
suspend fun CameraManager.openCamera(cameraId: String): CameraDevice? =
    suspendCoroutine { cont ->
        val callback = object : CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
            override fun onOpened(camera: CameraDevice) {
                cont.resume(camera)
            }

            override fun onDisconnected(camera: CameraDevice) {
                cont.resume(null)
            }

            override fun onError(camera: CameraDevice, error: Int) {
                // assuming that we don't care about the error in this example
                cont.resume(null) 
            }
        }
        openCamera(cameraId, callback, null)
    }
```

Now, in your application code you can just do `manager.openCamera(cameraId)` and get a reference to `CameraDevice` if it was opened successfully or `null` if it was not.

Comment: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-coroutines/blob/master/kotlin-coroutines-informal.md#wrapping-callbacks YES!  Thank you!!

Comment: how do you handle coroutine cancellation in this case?

Comment: @Bolein95: by using `suspendCancellableCoroutine` instead.

Comment: You can choose to represent your error with exception and do `cont.resumeWithException(CameraException(error))` or represent your error with a special result type and do `cont.resume(CameraErrorResult(error))`.

Comment: this is just perfect! I <3 coroutines! :)

Comment: Note that this will crash if the callback fires more than once, e.g. in some cases when rotating the device

Comment: @RomanElizarov Is it possible to expand your example to a scenario where you first add your listeners, and then run an `init` or `start` function. For example using the above code, lets assume nothing would happen until you run `CameraManager.start()`. How would chaining work in such a case? Hope my question makes sense.

Comment: Wouldn't it always be preferable to use `suspendCancellableCoroutine` in most cases?

Comment: `suspendCancellableCoroutine` is preferable when the underlying callback API provides the ability to cancel the ongoing operation.

Comment: Yes, it might crash with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already resumed` if for some reason callback is called twice, like if we keep an instance of some client which eventually calls callback method. How to workaround this?
Here is the actual example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61217073/crash-in-android-billingclient-with-coroutines

Comment: Any idea how to unit test this baby?

Answer (score 7):

Use suspendCancellableCoroutine instead of suspendCoroutine with proper exception handling

```
suspend fun CameraManager.openCamera(cameraId: String): CameraDevice? =
    suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
        val callback = object : CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
            override fun onOpened(camera: CameraDevice) {
                cont.resume(camera)
            }

            override fun onDisconnected(camera: CameraDevice) {
                cont.resume(null)
            }

            override fun onError(camera: CameraDevice, error: Int) {
                // Resume the coroutine by throwing an exception or resume with null
                cont.resumeWithException(/* Insert a custom exception */) 
            }
        }
        openCamera(cameraId, callback, null)
    }
```

It is preferable to always choose suspendCancellableCoroutine to handle cancellation of the coroutine scope, or to propagate cancellation from the underlying API.
[Source with other great examples](https://manuelvivo.dev/simplifying-apis-coroutines)

Answer (score -2):

I've used 2 solutions for this type of thing.

1: wrap the interface in an extension

```
CameraDevice.openCamera(cameraId: Integer, 
                onOpenedCallback: (CameraDevice) -> (), 
          onDisconnectedCallback: (CameraDevice) ->()) {

    manager.openCamera(cameraId, object : CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        override fun onOpened(openedCameraDevice: CameraDevice) {
            onOpenedCallback(openedCameraDevice)
        }

        override fun onDisconnected(cameraDevice: CameraDevice) {
            onDisconnectedCallback(cameraDevice)
        }
   })
}
```

2: Make a simple container class with a more functional interface:

```
class StateCallbackWrapper(val onOpened: (CameraDevice) -> (), val onClosed: (CameraDevice) ->()): CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
    override fun onOpened(openedCameraDevice: CameraDevice) {
        onOpened(openedCameraDevice)
    }

    override fun onDisconnected(cameraDevice: CameraDevice) {
        onClosed(cameraDevice)
    }
}
```

Personally I would start with something like these, and then build whatever threading differences on top of that.

Comment: I'm not clear: what does this buy me?  It calls the callbacks, so I still need to provide some sort of callback, so what it did was split out the single Callback (that holds 2 functions) into calling a method and passing in 2 distinct functions.  Unless that would enable `.await()`?

Comment: At the point of use you're passing lamdas or function references rather than having to create a whole object. Chances are the callbacks are already async. Are you just wanting to make a Class that manages the whole process?

Comment: The callbacks are async, but I'm trying to worm my way out of callback-hell and into something where I can chain functions for the default-path.  Like `manager.open(cameraId).capture().saveFile()`  Which requires me to block the manager.open(cameraId) call on some value getting filled (which I think should be with CompletableDeferred?) to tie it all together.

Comment: Classic example of indirection, where the problem is just moved under the guise of being fixed. We all do that from time to time. At least I do.

Comment: Looks like you missed the point here...