# How replace callback by Kotlin's coroutines

Tags: android, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I need to do the next:

1. Check is exist profile
2. If exist then start async http request (`getAdvertising()`) by Retrofit lib
3. if not exist then first loading profile from remote (by Retrofit) AND if success get result then start async http request (`getAdvertising()`)

I do this by callback like this:

```
    fun getAdvertising(callback: Callback<List<Advertising>>) {
        val call = myRestClient.advertising
        executeAsync(call, callback)
    }

  private fun <T> executeAsync(call: Call<T>, callback: Callback<T>) {
        val currentApplicationProfileResponse = foService.applicationProfileResponse
        if (currentApplicationProfileResponse == null) {
            getApplicationProfile(object : DefaultRestClientCallback<ApplicationProfileResponse>() {

                override fun onTransportResponse(transportResponse: TransportResponse) {
                    super.onTransportResponse(transportResponse)
                    if (transportResponse.isSuccessful) {
                        //asynchronously
                        call.enqueue(callback)
                    } else { // not success
                        if (callback is DefaultRestClientCallback<*>) {
                            callback.onTransportResponse(transportResponse)
                        } else {
                            callback.onResponse(call, transportResponse.originalResponse as Response<T>?)
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        } else { // appProfile is not null
            //asynchronously
            call.enqueue(callback)
        }
    }
```

Nice it's work fine.

But is to much code. Is it possible to repalace Callback by Kotlin's coroutines?

Comment: Retrofit has support now for coroutines: https://proandroiddev.com/suspend-what-youre-doing-retrofit-has-now-coroutines-support-c65bd09ba067

Comment: You should use Retrofit 2.6.0 it now supports coroutines or you can do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552925/existing-3-function-callback-to-kotlin-coroutines/48562175#48562175

Answer (score 3):

```
private fun getADvertise(onResult: (ArrayList<String>) -> Unit = {}) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        //Do Request To get Data using retrofit
        val result = ArrayList<String>()//result from retrofit
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main)
        {
            onResult(result)
        }

    }
}

private fun isProfileExist(): Boolean {
    //true or false
    return true
}

private fun getProfilePicture(id: String, OnResult: (String) -> Unit = {}) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        //Do Request To get Data using retrofit
        val result = "Link"//result from retrofit
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main)
        {
            OnResult(result)
        }

    }
}

//---------your main function------------------>
public fun execute(onResultMain: (ArrayList<String>) -> Unit = {}) {
    val exist = isProfileExist()
    if (exist) {
        getADvertise(onResultMain)
    } else {
        getProfilePicture("id") {

            getADvertise(onResultMain)
        }
    }

}
//onResultMain -> call back used to get result when they are ready ;)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `call.execute()` ( i.e, **synchronous retrofit request** ) *inside* `suspend` function of coroutine.

```
 suspend fun <T> executeAsync(call: Call<T>, callback: Callback<T>) {
       try {
           if(foService.applicationProfileResponse != null) {
              if(T is List<Advertising>) {
                 val advertisings = call.execute() // synchronous call 
              } 
           }
       } catch(e : Exception) {
           // handle exception
       } 
 }
```

Or, 
add

```
   .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
```

to retrofit builder and use `.await()` with `deferred`

```
    call.await() // call is of type deferred
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this way

```
suspend fun <T> Call<T>.getResult(): T = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
    enqueue(object : Callback<T> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>, t: Throwable) {
            cont.resumeWithException(t)
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>, response: Response<T>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                cont.resume(response.body()!!)
            } else {
                cont.resumeWithException(ErrorResponse(response.message(), response.code()))
            }
        }

    })
}
```

```
class ErrorResponse(message: String, code: Int) : Throwable(message )
```