# Crash in Android BillingClient with coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, play-billing-library

I'm getting notified that my Billing solution is crashing in a weird way. I'm unable to reproduce it or find a fix/bypass the problem. Maybe you could help.

`Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already resumed
       at kotlin.coroutines.SafeContinuation.resumeWith + 45(SafeContinuation.java:45)
       at com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientKotlinKt$querySkuDetails$2$1.onSkuDetailsResponse + 2(BillingClientKotlinKt.java:2)
       at com.android.billingclient.api.zzj.run + 8(zzj.java:8)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback + 907(Handler.java:907)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 105(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 216(Looper.java:216)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 7625(ActivityThread.java:7625)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 524(RuntimeInit.java:524)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 987(ZygoteInit.java:987)`

```
//billing
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:2.1.0'
```

Comment: I have same issue, too. Did you resolve this issue? @Cativail

Comment: Don't use billing-ktx, write it yourself

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: Implemented it on my own.

Comment: Can you share your solution as an answer? Many people will be thankful.

Comment: The bug is still present in version 3.0.0. Here's a link to the Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161586451

Answer (score 5):

Since last week we have this code running to prevent the exception:

```
suspend fun BillingClient.querySkuDetailsFixed(params: SkuDetailsParams) = suspendCancellableCoroutine<SkuDetailsResult> { continuation ->
querySkuDetailsAsync(params) { billingResult, skuDetails: List<SkuDetails>? ->
    if (continuation.isActive) {
        // doing some logging
        continuation.resumeWith(Result.success(SkuDetailsResult(billingResult, skuDetails)))
    } else {
      // Already resumed, doing some logging
    }
}
}
```

In the logs we see that we get 2 calls from the library:

The first response has always the BillingResponseCode -3 `SERVICE_TIMEOUT`.

The second response often has either 6 `ERROR` or 2 `SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE`.

In our case this is happening when the app is awaken in the background for a `PeriodicWorkRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

Update Google Play Billing Library to version 3.0.2 or newer. It was a bug in a library that is fixed according to [release notes](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/release-notes#3-0-2):

> Fixed a bug in the Kotlin extension where the coroutine fails with error "Already resumed".

Answer (score 0):

I can 100% reproduce this crash, even using latest billing 5.0.0:
`"com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:5.0.0"`.

I'm trying to wrap callback-base API for billing into coroutines:

```
private suspend fun doStart() {
        if (billingClient.isReady) {
            return
        }

        suspendCoroutine { cont ->
            val callback = object : BillingClientStateListener {
                override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                    cont.resumeWithException(RuntimeException())
                }

                override fun onBillingSetupFinished(result: BillingResult) {
                    when (result.responseCode) {
                        BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK -> cont.resume(true)
                        else -> cont.resumeWithException(RuntimeException())
                    }
                }
            }

            billingClient.startConnection(callback)
        }
    }
```

So, I start my `billingClient` lazily in `onResume` of single `MainActivity` and load active in-app purchases. As you can see from this method `doStart()`, it first checks `billingClient.isReady`, to avoid multiple starts.

I also have `open-app ads` integrated to my app, and let's say Open App Ad starts every 2nd COLD open of the app  (COLD - after the app being killed, i.e. in `onCreate()`). We Open App Ad shows, it covers the entire screen.

So the crash happens in 100% cases when it's about time to show Open App Ad. Some conflict between started->then->resumed `MainActivity` and `Ad proxy Activity`. Stacktrace is exactly same, pointing to the line in `onBillingServiceDisconnected()`:

`cont.resumeWithException(RuntimeException())`.