# How to convert Play Store API calls to suspend functions

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-billing

Converting my own http calls to KTor (& therefore coroutines) is a bit hollow, or at least not terribly satisfying, without also being able to convert Play Store API calls and their callbacks to use suspend functions.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552925/existing-3-function-callback-to-kotlin-coroutines/48562175#48562175) general answer, with specific example of a different API, is fabulous and I've managed to use it to produce something for "startBillingClient", as follows

```
private suspend fun BillingClient.startConnection(value: Int) = 
    suspendCoroutine<Unit> { cont ->
        val callback = object: BillingClientStateListener {
            override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: 
                                              BillingResult) {
                isServiceConnected = true
            }

            override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                isServiceConnected = false
                startConnection(this)
            }
        }
    startConnection(callback)
}
```

but now I'm struggling with producing something similar for querySkuDetailsAsync, which seems to be due to needing to pass parameters in. Should be easy, but...

Comment: You didn't implement it right. The coroutine will never resume. I'm not sure if a `suspend fun` is even the right tool for what you're doing. Sounds like a long-running background task and the listener is responding to a sequence of events instead of a single event that represents the completion of the action.

Comment: HI @Marko, I think this *is* a response to a single event, starting the Play Store billing client. Aren't all the API calls for the Play Store single event/single response calls. Back to here, though, what's needed, cont.resume?

Comment: Yes, `cont.resume` with nothing else inside. It's not a good practice to have business logic inside the `suspendCoroutine` block. Its only purpose is adapting from an async API to a `suspend fun`.