# Forcing a third party API to run on a different thread

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-mediacodec

I am encoding audio and video using the MediaCodec. I start a coroutine that runs the encoding using Dispatchers.IO:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    videoEncoder.setCallback(object : MediaCodec.Callback() {
        override fun onOutputBufferAvailable(mc: MediaCodec, bufferId: Int, bufferInfo: MediaCodec.BufferInfo) {
           // The thread here is "main" even though a coroutine was launched using Dispatchers.IO
           Log.i("encoder", "Thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().name)
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the asynchronous callback of MediaCodec to receive the encoded data. But the code inside onOutputBufferAvailable runs on the "main" thread, which is bad. Is there a way to force the encoder to run on the IO thread. Unfortunately, creating another coroutine inside onOutputBufferAvailable is not an option as creating a new coroutine each time the callback is called is way too expensive and will degrade performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your main concern is to run the code in the thread other than "main", but you don't necessarily need a coroutine context, then you can create a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) running on your background thread and then pass it to `setCallback()` method.

Also, please note that coroutines are very lightweight. You can run thousands or even millions of coroutines concurrently and nothing bad really happens. I'm not sure about creating a coroutine from outside of the coroutine context - it may involve some latency. I suggest testing the performance first, if you did not do it yet.

Comment: Found that solution just after posting. Still, it is bound to happen that some third party API doesn't offer a way to run it on a different thread, so knowing how to deal with it is still good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's something that happens from time to time.
You don't actually have a guarantee where the callback will be called.
IMHO the best way here will be to guide coroutine.
I would prefer using a [suspendCoroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552925/existing-3-function-callback-to-kotlin-coroutines) block with a [Continuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552925/existing-3-function-callback-to-kotlin-coroutines).

Here you go a simple [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552925/existing-3-function-callback-to-kotlin-coroutines).

In your case you can do next:

```
suspendCoroutine<Int> { cont ->
            videoEncoder.setCallback(object : MediaCodec.Callback() {
                override fun onOutputBufferAvailable(
                    mc: MediaCodec,
                    bufferId: Int,
                    bufferInfo: MediaCodec.BufferInfo
                ) {
                    // The thread here is "main" even though a coroutine was launched using Dispatchers.IO
                    cont.resume(bufferId)
                }
            })
        }
```

P.S. Pay attention that you will wait until a callback will be triggered.

P.P.S. feel free to adjust the Dispatchers stuff within your needs, provide any.