# Kotlin create a custom coroutine

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I am trying to make a coroutine from a method that I have.
to make things simple, let's say I have a `class A` that I try to `connect()` and it is connected only after `class B` that is inside `A` is connected.

So, I have this code for example, which offcourse doesn't work but it's just to show my use case-

```
class A {
    fun connect() {
        classB.connect()
        val isConnected = classB.isConnected
    }
}

class B {
    val isConnected: Boolean = false
    fun connect() {
        someObject.connect( SomeListenerInterface {
            override fun onSuccess() {
                isConnected = true
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I want to make the `classB.connect()` as a coroutine, and make it suspended, so only when it is done, the line of `val isConnected = classB.isConnected` would execute and the value would be set properly.

If I would use java and callbacks, I would just pass a callback to the `classB.connect()` method, and set the `class A.isConnected` value inside this callback.

is it possible with kotlin coroutines?
Thanks

Comment: The first thing you need here is convert you callback based `someObject.connect` function into a suspend function. You can do that using `suspendCancellableCoroutine` builder. Now that `someObject.connect` is suspend, you need to mark `B.connect` as `suspend`. The last bit required is a `CoroutineScope` which is a bridge between non-coroutine and coroutine based world. Since you haven't provided the exact code and mentioned what it is doing, it's not possible to suggest the coroutine code but what I wrote earlier is the gist of what you need to do.

Comment: @ArpitShukla thanks for the suggestion. I think I will just use something like `val ack = CompletableDeferred<Boolean>()` inside `classB` and I will write `ack.complete(true)` inside `classB.connect()` and in `classA.connect()` I will just do `classB.await()` after the `classB.connect()`. what do you think?

Comment: @StackerSapper this is unnecessary, you should instead follow what Arpit said, which is detailed in Kirill's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert callback to suspend function using [suspendCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html). The function below returns `true` when the connection succeeds:

```
class B {
    suspend fun connect(): Boolean = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
        someObject.connect(object : SomeListenerInterface {
            override fun onSuccess() {
                continuation.resume(true)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

`connect` function in `class A` should be `suspend` respectively:

```
class A {
    suspend fun connect() {
        val isConnected = classB.connect()
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, though does the solution with `CompletableDeferred<Boolean>()` isn't good also? because I have many callbacks that are relatd to each other

Comment: I relied on the [Roman Elizarov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1051598/roman-elizarov), the Kotlin founder, [opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552925/existing-3-function-callback-to-kotlin-coroutines/48562175#48562175).